# Is "eval" the only way to include the code from a call to file_get_contents (or from a string)?

Tags: php, php-5.3, php-include

I want to do the equivalent of an include but on a string, not on a file path. I would be getting the contents of a file, then manipulating the contents of it and then including that altered code/string as PHP code in the calling PHP page. (This will be for internal use only, so it's not the usual security risk)

Example:

```
<?php
    //This is "code.php", a file that has some code (elided in this example)
    <REPLACE_ME_WITH_OTHER_CODE>
?>

<?php
    $code = $myObj->manipulate( file_get_contents( "code.php" ) );

    //Now include it (eval?)
    eval( $code );

    //Or some other way?
    include_code( $code );
?>
```

Comment: Even for internal use it's still a bad idea because code that modifies code is nigh-unmaintainable. But yes, `eval()` is the only way.

Comment: Theoretically you could do it by writing your code to a pipe and then using include on the pipe. Other than using `include()` instead of `eval()`, I'm not sure what the purpose of jumping through these hoops would be though.

Comment: You could turn URL includes on, but that's just a bad idea even if you're not so worried about security.

Comment: @NickCoons How do I write to an include a pipe? What version of PHP is required? Do you have a link to an example?

Comment: Why can't you just "include" the file itself? Or write the code contents to another file and include that file. But not sure what context this is being used for so not sure which would be the best for your situation.

Comment: You can [register a stream wrapper](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stream-wrapper-register.php) that wraps arround a variable and include that (Example #1)

Comment: Eval vs. eval substitute will have the same potential security issues but without the benefit of returning value. Why would you want to work around eval? Check out http://www.php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php.php. you might be able to echo the scipt and catch it with php://stdin as a stream using include, but this will be functionality equivalent to eval.